# Why we capitalize all race names but our own

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6668/1693) about alien species and planets brought up something I've been thinking about on and off for years.

We capitalize names of alien races like *Vulcan*, *Timelord*, *Cylon* (well, maybe not alien), *Krell*, *Nox*, *Minbari*, and so on, but we never capitalize *human*.

So how did we end up capitalizing names for sentient species when we don't do that for our own race?

Comment: The title would have been funnier if you had left "our own" all lowercase ;)

Comment: Maybe you wacky sci-fi people like to capitalize everything, but here in fantasyland our elves, dwarves, dragons, centaurs, merfolk, and other non-human human-rivals are all lowercase.

Comment: @jwodder Yeah, but see, elves, dwarves, dragons and the like all live on the planet with us. Otherwise, they'd be Vulcan elves, Skrullian dwarves, and Alderanian dragons.

Comment: Mike Resnick's works have always capitalized "Man" as the name of our species. Probably not coincidentally, they also often feature other species talking about Man.

Comment: Keep in mind that none of those others exist.

Comment: @HotLicks: But they do within the realm of the works in which those names are used.

Comment: I would capitalize Martian if referring to a little green man, but not if referring to a martian landscape.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Most of the names you give are derived from proper place names, or clan names, or such, so using "human" as a comparison is not accurate.

For instance, Vulcan and Minbari are named for their planets. We would capitalize Terran likewise (or Earthling or Martian).

Also Krell, Nox, and Timelord are groups of peoples (my apologies for not using a panxenic term, but "beings" was too confusing). We would likewise capitalize Irish, Passamaquoddy, Vandals, etc. (And naturally, Timelords are Gallifreyan, just as Mongols are Terran.) Or if you consider them more like ethnicities, you would still capitalize them, like you do with Jewish, Native American, Latina, etc.

Also, in response to Vulcans born off-world as still being Vulcans, I'd make the argument that Asians born in America (for instance) are still often called Asian, or Asian-American.

And finally, I think and I know I may well be dunned for it, that Cylon was a "brand" name for the original cybernetic organisms.  And we would likewise capitalize Sunbeam, Keurig, General Electric, etc.

So then by example, human is not capitalized because it is not a proper noun, and not derived from a proper noun. Vulcans, Minbari, and Timelords are humanoid beings. There are also reptilian beings, silicon beings, and energy beings, but we don't capitalize any of those types of beings (human, humanoid, reptilian, silicon, energy, etc).

It is a good question, though.  [Here](http://www.writingforums.org/showthread.php?t=19253) is a discussion that you may find interesting.

Comment: And thanks for the link, too.  I'm glad to see I'm not the only writer to have pondered this.

Comment: I love the line "Cylon was a brand"

Comment: Branding is important if you're going to take over the human race

Comment: I find *groups of beings* awfully vague, especially now that this is an EL&U question.  Are humans not a group of beings?  Also, the Irish come from Ireland; thus they fall under the Vulcan example.  It is more debatable whether the Vandals are named after their place of origin.

Comment: The more I think about it, there's a problem with a group named after a place.  We may use Terrans, but then is it right to call humans born and raised in a culture on Mars "Terran?"  Vulcans, even if they've lived on Vulcan, are still referred to with a capital V.  And Timelords are from Gallifrey, not Timelordia, so that's not a name derived from a place name.

Comment: @TangoOversway: Personally, I would capitalize *Gallifreyans* but *not* capitalize *time lord*.  But that's just me.  (I recognize that it is customary to capitalize *Time Lord*.)

Comment: +1, but I would have made another account just to +1 twice if instead of Keurig you had picked another brand that was famous for their toasters.

Comment: Back when people were much more racist than they are today, the different "races" were all capitalized –– e.g., Negro, Caucasian, Oriental. I am sure this had an influence on this practice.

Comment: @Joel Believe me, I wracked my brain trying to think of a good toaster brand.

Comment: "So then by example, human is not capitalized because it is not a proper noun, and not derived from a proper noun." Not entirely true. _Human_ can be traced back to common origins with Germanic _Mannus_ and Hindu _Manu_, proper names of deities considered to be the progenitor of humans. It's far back enough we don't know if the gods or people were named first. _Terra_, ironically, can not - it just means "land" or "dry".

Comment: I like the logic that the race name is derived from the planet, and therefore proper, but I would point out that there are races who are not named for their planet, who are still most commonly given a capital. For example, the Klingon homeworld is in fact Qo'noS, and not a one of the Mass Effect races are named for their planet — Krogan come from Tuchanka, Salarians from Sur'Kesh, etc.

Comment: I would argue we call Vulcans such not because they are from the planet Vulcans, specifically, but because they are off a unique race, named for their home world. A panther born on Earth might be a Terran, but it's still a panther; likewise, a panther born on Mars is a Martian, but still a panther as well. So perhaps a Vulcan born on Earth would be a Terran Vulcan, or just a Vulcan from Earth.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think some writers in some contexts *would* capitalize "Human", especially in the context of interstellar sentient races, just as some writers capitalize Earth when referring to the planet in the context of other named planets.

I think the case for not capitalizing *human* is that we normally use it as a common noun, not a proper one.  For example, we would write "there are people over there".  We could just as well write "there are humans over there", but we wouldn't use "there are People over there".

I'm actually all for capitalizing Human and Earth in science fiction, though some writers will opt for different words instead, such as *Terran* (as mentioned in Kit's answer), so that the "properness" of the name is clearer.

Comment: The planet Earth is generally capitalized, not only in fiction. "*Some* writers capitalize Earth when referring to the planet" is therefore not correct – they *all* do that.

Comment: The more I think about this question, the more I think the easiest solution is to just start capitalizing Human when it refers to the species and using "human" when referring to behavior or other loose usage.

Comment: @Felix: No, I have definitely seen writers use *earth* to mean the planet Earth, both generally and in science fiction.  I fully agree that it *should* be capitalized (and if I were an editor, I would insist on it), but in the real world, many writers simply don't.

Comment: This has been (inconclusively) discussed: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2286/8019

Answer (score 2):

Capitalization has *nothing* to do with conventions in any particular genre. In English, we capitalize proper nouns and adjectives derived from proper nouns. Vulcan, Earthling, and Venusian are all adjectives derived from the proper nouns Vulcan Earth, and Venus. Human is not a proper noun, any more the elf, dwarf, people, or purple-people-eater.

We capitalize Earth (or Venus, or Mars, or Terra, or Cygnus-XYJ) when referring to a planet, celestial body, or crazed celebrity brand pseudonym, because those would all be proper nouns. We do not capitalize earth when we mean dust or soil.

Incidentally, we capitalize Elf when we are referring to the movie, and I suppose if we were to start talking about the main character's dizzy, breathless wonder as "a thing" we might describe someone, somewhere, as being Elfian, but please don't.

I have a related post at http://wp.me/p1RPTJ-6x

Comment: Elfan, surely :-)

Comment: So.. Earthhumans is fine?

Answer (score 1):

I checked in in this because I am writing a scifi story and was running into the issue. I have concluded Earth is capitalized when discussing the place, but not the soil. And Human is capitalized when discussing the species as a specific people but not a classification. For example, the Human ambassador versus the ambassador's human nature.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hasn't this already been given in answers, JD?

Comment: You're talking about a general rule of usage. For instance, if I'm talking about Johnny's female parent, I'll write "Johnny's mom," but if I'm talking about mine, and am calling her, I'll be writing, "Hey, Mom, can you look at this?" So that's my first thought on this. The second is that I have yet to see this rule used with the word human.