# What is the correct capitalization of the words earth and moon?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I believe that Earth means planet and earth means soil. But I've seen earth used in published works to mean the planet earth. But no one writes jupiter.

Similarly, Moon should mean the name of Earth's moon and lower case moon means the general category. This one is more complicated because I've read that the name of Earth's moon is Luna. Except no one calls it that. We don't say "Neil Armstrong was the first man on Luna."

Am I correct or is this a matter of convention?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it correct to capitalise 'earth'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/when-is-it-correct-to-capitalise-earth)

Answer (score 3):

According to *Garner's Modern American Usage*, when referring to the planet we live on, when used with the definite article, it is "the earth", lower case. However, when it is used as a name for the planet without an article, like "Mars is smaller than Earth", you capitalize it. It says sun and moon are treated the same way.

Comment: 'Earth is bigger than Moon'? You're having us on.

Comment: Hmmmm . . . right. That's what I get copying things out of book without thinking.

Answer (score 3):

## The bottom line is that there is little consensus in all usage cases, but guidelines exist.

**Typically, we capitalize the names of astronomical bodies, except when there's a preceding article** ("Earth" or "the earth"). Earth is never capitalized when referring to soil or land—only when referring to the planet as a whole.

**NASA and ESA (among others) prefer to capitalize Moon when referring to Earth's moon as a special case.** My guess is that nobody says "Moon is out tonight!", as they would with Jupiter or Venus. We always add "the" to the Moon. It's as if we give it special consideration because doesn't have its own, standalone name. (Some may disagree on this point, preferring to always refer to it always as "the moon", following the rule mentioned above.)

- Correct: "*The* sun is far from *the* earth."
- Correct: "*The* sun is far from *Earth*."
- Correct: "Jupiter has several *moons*."
- Correct: "*The Moon* is right next to the horizon."
- Incorrect: "*The Earth* is far from *the Sun*."
- Incorrect: "*The Sun* gives light to our *moon*."
- Incorrect (debatable): "*The moon* is bright tonight."

There are a number of excellent examples on the MLA page here:
https://style.mla.org/2016/11/07/capitalizing-earth-sun-moon/

Note also that the name of our host star, the sun, is "Sol". We can say "Sol is larger than Earth", or "The Sun is larger than Earth" or "The sun is out today", but we would say "Sol is larger than Earth" rather than "Sun is larger than Earth".

Answer (score 0):

Astronomers and others involved in space travel and exploration typically capitalize "the Earth" (or alternatively just "Earth") <strike>and "the Moon,"</strike> although there are many counterexamples. When moons in general are discussed, the M is not capitalized.

*edit:* Actually, this turns out to be more complicated than I expected. The European Space Agency [prefers to capitalize the M in "Moon"](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Operations/ESA_teams_ready_for_Moon_landing), but NASA [tends to favor a small m](http://moon.nasa.gov/). (Ties should go to [Neil DeGrasse Tyson](http://www.haydenplanetarium.org/tyson/), in my opinion, and he seems to favor a [capital M](http://www.haydenplanetarium.org/tyson/read/1994/05/01/celestial-windings).)

I believe *Luna* (along with its sidekick, *Terra*) is a convention from science fiction and is not used by actual scientists.

Comment: *Luna* and *Terra* are the Latin names for our moon and our planet, hence words in English like *lunar* and *terrain*. This of course predates science fiction by some millennia.

Comment: Yes, they are Latin words. Use of them in English as proper names for the Moon and the Earth remains largely confined to science fiction.

Comment: I commented because I read "convention" as including "origin" somewhat. The term *Lunarian* was popular in the earth 18th century as an inhabitant of the moon. Today it might be popular to call the moon *Luna* in science fiction (I don't know, I don't read the genre), but all sorts of words are in use today outside of sci-fi that relate to *Terra* and *Luna*, if not those forms of the words, specifically, while the last line of your answer seems to imply otherwise.

Comment: With all due respect, if I had meant origin, I would have said origin. "Convention" merely means a customary way of doing something.

Comment: I understand that, hence why I mentioned my interpretation, but it still stands that to say terms like *Luna* and *Terra* are not used by actual scientists is, frankly, ignorant, and it's why I can't give your answer a vote.

Comment: You can prove me wrong by finding the word "Luna" [in use at nasa.gov](https://www.google.com/search?q="luna"+site:nasa.gov) to refer to Earth's moon in English. Have at it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13116/discussion-between-tylerh-and-phenry)

Comment: @TylerH 'Luna and Terra are the Latin names for our moon and our planet, hence words in English like lunar and terrain. This of course predates science fiction by some millennia.' I thought they _invented_ SF.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, modern science fiction as we know it, a la Arthur C. Clarke.

Comment: @phenry: According to NASA's historical and [style guide](https://history.nasa.gov/printFriendly/styleguide.html), and [the website](http://moon.nasa.gov/home.cfm) you linked, NASA prefers "Moon" over "moon".