# Sun and earth in combination as proper nouns

Tags: proper-nouns

I have done an extensive research and I am aware that Sun and Earth can be ordinary and proper nouns depending on the context.  I am writing the engineering text, which is also concerned with transfer of energy and light between Earth/earth and Sun/sun.

I initially used capitalised forms, Sun and Earth.  I gave my text for editing, and curiously, the editor changed Sun to sun and left Earth intact.  So what I got in the end is something like that

> A typical example of heat transfer by radiation occurs between the **sun**
>   and the **Earth**.

This looks a bit inconsistent to me.  What would you suggest?

Would it be OK if I put both Earth and Sun to uncapitalised form?

Thanks for the advices.

**EDIT**: this might be interesting:

1. Serway's textbook consistently use Sun and Earth,
2. Incropera's textbook consistently use sun, while earth in used in about 90% of cases.

They both seem to be pretty consistent to me.

Comment: This [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/371502/44619) has a few examples with sun written in lowercase or in uppercase, and includes a link to MLA center.

Comment: related: [When is it correct to capitalise 'earth'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/when-is-it-correct-to-capitalise-earth) and [About definite article before “Earth”, “Moon” and “Sun”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33282/about-definite-article-before-earth-moon-and-sun)

Comment: @FumbleFingers wrote: [*When the Earth is spoken of as a physical body, occupying space-time, it's normally preceded by the article, and often capitalised. As are Sun and Moon, but there's no universality about either convention, nor is capitalisation necessarily governed by whether the article is present or not. I've capitalised every usage after the article, as do most people, but there are exceptions.*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/33293/44619)

Comment: I would capitalise both terms, as they are referring to the name of a planet and a star; but first check with a colleague or a professor.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know the principles and have read dozens of articles on this topic.  What bugs me that I would opt for both capitalised or both non-capitalised.  I am surprised by the choice of the editor.

Comment: I do sympathise, but unless an astrophysicist posts an official answer, we have to settle with "do what your instincts tell you". Have you asked the editor why they chose the lowercase for *sun*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because editing was done through the firm, I cannot contact the editor.  Of course, my decision is final, I just want to make a proper decision.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your instinct, if you see *sun* with a lower case S, is to use the lower case for *Earth* as well.  However, *earth* has a different meaning than *Earth*.  The planet we live on is *Earth* or *the Earth*; the soil we plant our crops in is *earth*.

Here's a definition with the lower case:

> the loose substance of which a large part of the surface of the ground is made, and in which plants can grow; the land surface of the earth rather than the sky or sea: *The plowed earth looked dark and fertile.*

If you read some other folks' articles with these two words written with sun and Earth, I think you'll get more used to it.